# creating a one on one chat inside an asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, chat

i would like to create a facebook like one on one chat within an asp.net website, but i cant figure out the mechanism or how it would work.

so far i only have a database table for it designed like this:

```
    id | user1 | user2 | datetime | message
```

how do i get started, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd consider utilising Signal R for this type of feature - see this guide on implementing a chat feature with signal r - should remove a lot of pain from the development process http://geekswithblogs.net/jeroenb/archive/2011/12/14/signalr-starter-application.aspx

Comment: thank you it works great but how do i simulate a one on one chat using it.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:
[Simple Chat Application in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8307/Simple-Chat-Application-in-ASP-NET)

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method to build a chat in asp.net is to use a [IHttpAsyncHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.aspx) and ajax requests.

Here is a [completely working project that implements this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42734/Using-IHttpAsyncHandler-and-XMLHttpRequest-to-push), along with ajax.

An async request allows you to delay the response of a request till an external event occurs.
A user makes a call to this handler and waits till someone sends him a message.
Messages are delivered as soon as you send them to a user. 
On receiving a message the client makes another request and waits for the next message.
This is a lot more efficient than polling the site to check if messages have arrived.

Using the async handler also ensures that no asp.net threads are wasted waiting while a user waits for messages to come.

This ensures that you chat can scale well even as the number of users of the site goes up.